# Passing the host's current user to to vagrant shell provisioner

Tags: vagrant

I want to pass the current user within my Vagrantfile, but I'm not sure how to do it.

I've tried this:

`config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "echo $(whoami) > /etc/profile.d/me"`

But it results in 'root' being put into the file, which I assume is the vagrant host's user. I want to get the username for the host.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
username = "#{ENV['USERNAME'] || `whoami`}"
config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "echo #{username} > /etc/profile.d/me"
```

This way it will work on Linux or Microsoft systems.